# Prevent scoped enum to be copyable / moveable?

Tags: c++, c++17

Perhaps silly question:

Is there a way in C++ to prevent an enum class type to be copyable?

Comment: Why would one ever to do that?

Comment: I tried to build an atomic type for a µC. Using an ordinary class it is allways accessed via a pointer in assembler, even it could be directly accessed, e.g. it is in global scope and not a ref-parameter to a function. Using an enum type does optimize that but gives me a copyable type.

Comment: Are you sure you're not optimizing compiler-specifically? The assembler generated surely depends on the compiler used as well as the options.

Comment: Yes, it would be a specific optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Enumerations are integers. And integers are always copy/moveable.

You could of course make an actual class that is constructed from the enumerations. And that class can be immobile. But that's about it.